# Make a bar in a chart remain highlighted when it is clicked in Ext JS?

Tags: javascript, extjs

In `Ext.chart.Chart`, when a bar is clicked, I want it to remain highlighted until another bar is clicked. How do I do that?

Comment: What did you tried yourself so far?

Comment: I tried the following : obj.sprite.el.dom.setAttribute("fill","#333");
Because of this, the bar is getting highlighted. But now I have to remove its highlight when I click another bar.

Answer (score 0):

*Although I think your question is incomplete and you could provide us with some code, I created a [Sencha Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/tv6) to show you how to highlight items in a bar chart.*

Before I provide you with some code I want to tell you what my steps were. I never worked with the charts library, so I went from blank. I almost never have to hack into the dom, and seeing ExtJs as a mature framework I take for granted that ExtJs  will provide me with the functionality you are asking for.

## Steps I took

1. I want to hook in on a itemclick, does a item of a chart an
   [`itemclick`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.chart.series.Bar-event-itemclick) event?
2. Yes, it does. I can configure an itemclick listener on the [`series`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.chart.series.Series). The docs tell me that, when I want to use itemevents,
   I have to configure a [`ItemEvents`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.chart.plugin.ItemEvents) plugin.
3. After configure a `itemclick` on the `series` and configure the `plugin` on the `chart` I look which parameters are provided. Great,
   the series and the clicked item are already provided. Now I can use
   [`setHighlightItem()`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.chart.series.Series-method-setHighlightItem) of the `series` to `hightlight` the
   clicked item.
4. So in the `itemclick` I can call `series.setHighlightItem(item)` but it doesn't work. Why? Must I configure a `highlight`? Yes.
5. After setting [`highlight`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.chart.series.Series-cfg-highlight) on true, or configure a object (for some styling) it works like a charm.

## Code of the Fiddle

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function() {
        Ext.create('Ext.Container', {
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            width: 600,
            height: 400,
            layout: 'fit',
            items: {
                xtype: 'cartesian',
                // hightlight item on click
                //interactions: 'itemhighlight', // --> don't set an interaction
                plugins: {
                    ptype: 'chartitemevents',
                    moveEvents: true
                },
                // eo hightlight item on click
                store: {
                    fields: ['name', 'value'],
                    data: [{
                        name: 'metric one',
                        value: 10
                    }, {
                        name: 'metric two',
                        value: 7
                    }, {
                        name: 'metric three',
                        value: 5
                    }, {
                        name: 'metric four',
                        value: 2
                    }, {
                        name: 'metric five',
                        value: 27
                    }]
                },
                axes: [{
                    type: 'numeric',
                    position: 'left',
                    title: {
                        text: 'Sample Values',
                        fontSize: 15
                    },
                    fields: 'value'
                }, {
                    type: 'category',
                    position: 'bottom',
                    title: {
                        text: 'Sample Values',
                        fontSize: 15
                    },
                    fields: 'name'
                }],
                series: {
                    type: 'bar',
                    xField: 'name',
                    yField: 'value',
                    style: {
                        fill: 'blue'
                    },
                    
                    // hightlight item on click
                    highlight: {
                        strokeStyle: 'black',
                        lineDash: [5, 3]
                    },
                    listeners: {
                        itemclick: function(series, item, event, eOpts) {
                            series.setHighlightItem(item);
                        }
                    }
                    // eo hightlight item on click
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For ExtJS 6.x, you can override (or extend) the `updateHighlightItem` method of `Ext.chart.AbstractChart`:

```
Ext.override(Ext.chart.AbstractChart, {
    updateHighlightItem: function (newHighlightItem, oldHighlightItem) {
        if (!newHighlightItem || newHighlightItem === oldHighlightItem) {
            this.setHighlightItem(oldHighlightItem);
            return
        }
        if (oldHighlightItem) {
            oldHighlightItem.series.setAttributesForItem(oldHighlightItem, {highlighted: false});
        }
        if (newHighlightItem) {
            newHighlightItem.series.setAttributesForItem(newHighlightItem, {highlighted: true});
            this.fireEvent('itemhighlight', this, newHighlightItem, oldHighlightItem);
        }
        this.fireEvent('itemhighlightchange', this, newHighlightItem, oldHighlightItem);
    }
})
```